# how to sum multiple row data using pandas and data is excel formet

Tags: python, pandas

Hi Everyone how to sum multiple row data using pandas and the data is excel format, and sum only edwin and maria data,please help me out thanks in advance.

**excel data**

|  | name | salary | incentive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | john | 2000 | 400 |
| 1 | edwin | 3000 | 600 |
| 2 | maria | 1000 | 200 |

**expected output**

|  | name | salary | incentive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Total | 5000 | 1000 |
| 1 | john | 2000 | 400 |
| 2 | edwin | 3000 | 600 |
| 3 | maria | 1000 | 200 |

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the Total line, you need the sums of 'john', 'edwin', not edwin and maria. I used the isin function, which returns a boolean mask, which is then used to select the desired rows (the ind variable). In the dataframe, the line with Total is filled with sums. Then pd.concat is used to concatenate the remaining lines. On the account sum in Excel, do not understand what you want?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['john', 'edwin', 'maria'], 'salary':[2000, 3000, 1000], 'incentive':[400, 600, 200]})
ind = df['name'].isin(['john', 'edwin'])

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Total'], 'salary':[df.loc[ind, 'salary'].sum()], 'incentive':[df.loc[ind, 'incentive'].sum()]})
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df])
df1 = df1.reset_index().drop(columns='index')
print(df1)
```

Output

```
    name  salary  incentive
0  Total    5000       1000
1   john    2000        400
2  edwin    3000        600
3  maria    1000        200
```